# Dynamic connection string windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, connection-string

I believe this is going to be marked as duplicate as there are many questions similar but I could not find one that answers to my exact question.

I am developing a windows forms application that is using an SQL Server and I need to give the user the ability to edit the connection string of the application. The changes the user makes should be persistent across different sessions of my application, so if user changes the database name the next time he is going to run the application the application will use the updated value for the database without any need to recompile.

I have tried using the settings section with no luck.I have tried using the following code for update connection string but the change is not persistent across application sessions:
`config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString = "";
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified,true);
 ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");`

What would be the correct approach?Should I use an external config file for the connections string?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to have the default connection string in the app.config, and the user's customised version in a separate file which is created on demand. At least then you have a fallback if the user specifies an invalid connection.

Comment: stuartd I can live with that, is there any proposed way of using an external configuration file for storing the connection string, so that when the user runs the installer the external configuration file will be automatically generated and stored in his pc?

Comment: Most of the connection string won't change, usually just the server and/or database.  Store those in the registry and construct the connstring on the fly.  That's how I do it.